# Best way to store an application log on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging

In my company we have developed many automation applications that syncs data from and to our platform and third party platforms.

Our applications at this time store logs on Sqlite.

Since we ensure our customers the integrity of the synced data, through an internal frontend, we daily check the logs to catch every possible problem and to proceed (possibly) manually.
Our internal frontend allow us to filter datetime ranges, the different flow each application can have, and see a full detail of the flow of each execution.

Now we wanto to move the log part of aour application on AWS and I wonder which service is more suitable for our needs. DynamoDB seems good, but it might result in excessive costs if we increase our customer portfolio, CloudWatch is also a choice, but I cannot find an online article that does not concern system or service logs.

Any clue is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you already have a solution that uses SQL, is there any reason you aren't looking at one of the AWS database services that use SQL, like Aurora or Redshift?

Comment: Good question: the architecture we want to use should be able (in a nearly future) to accept logs from different kind of applications and thus the flexibility to use a schema-less db is a plus point to solutions like DynamoDB.

Also, our logs could be stocked/standardized in two "tables" one for the executions and one for the details, so we think that a relational db is a waste of features (and maybe money)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store logs only for short duration for some processing; surely you can put them in DynamoDB; do your processing ( probably using EMR); and then purge logs.

If you want to store logs for long-term; S3 is the right solution.. You can still do processing on S3 using Athena or EMR .. Putting them on S3 would be very cheap.

Looks like you don't have much data.. I think DynamoDB could be your best best as it is not very expensive if you provision it for Low IOPS.. Athena is better if u have TBs of data.. You can also explore MongoDB.. Many people use it to store logs because it is schema less; and you can install MongoDB on any unix server very easily.. So, you will not have to spend any money.. Regarding taking back-ups is also super easy in MongoDB . You just need to copy a folder somewhere else. Done.

Comment: Athena sounds very interesting, thanks, but since our sync applications runs 24/7, and each day I need to check all their log, wouldn't it cost me more than a DynamoDB-based solution?